# Showing $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(b^{n}-a^{n}\right)$ is divergent for $a,b \geq 1, a \neq b$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Let $a,b > 0$. Show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(b^{n}-a^{n}\right)$ is divergent for $a,b \geq 1,a \neq b$.**

This is a smallere sub problem of a bigger problem. *I have investigated the convergence for all other combinations then* $a,b \geq 1$. Also, I can't use the fact if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b^{n}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^{n}$
is divergent then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(b^{n}-a^{n}\right)$ is also divergent.

Kind regards,

Comment: What about $a=b=1$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy
I have solved the more general case $a=b$. So yes, $a=b=1$ has been taken care of.

Comment: I hope you mean disproven, since $a=b$ implies convergence to zero.

Comment: Your title and the question are both wrong. You should add the condition $a \neq b$.

Answer (score 3):

Excluding the choice of $a,b$ that was pinpointed in the comments: $a=b=1$, that is, assume $a \neq b$. Now, write

$$ a^n - b^n = a^n \underbrace{ \left( 1 - \left( \dfrac{b}{a} \right)^n \right) }_{ (*)} $$

Now, if $a > b$, then $\dfrac{b}{a} < 1$ and $(b/a)^n \to 0$. Hence, $(*) \to 1$ and we have that $b^n - a^n \to \infty $ and the divergence test  gives divergence of the series.

How about it $b>a$? Can you do this case?

Comment: Yes, but again: I probably has to prove that $b^{n}-a^{n} \rightarrow \infty$ for $n \to \infty$

Comment: This is for $a > b \geq 1$. Right?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $a=b$, then convergence trivially follows. If not, without loss of generality assume that $b>a\geq1$. What can you then say about the following limit?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}b^n-a^n$$

Comment: Divergence to $+\infty$. But this is not a proof nor is it sufficient.

Comment: Divergence of the terms of the sequence to $\infty$ _is_ sufficient to show divergence of the series - a series can converge _only if_ the terms of the summation go to zero as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: But I have to prove that it does not convergent to 0. 
Which is probably manageable now that I think about it.

Comment: Can I just show that $b^n$ converges to $+\infty$ and $a^n$ to $-\infty$?

Comment: No. That gives the limit being $\infty-\infty$, which is indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

If $a \neq b$ and $a,b \geq 1$ we get $|b^{n}-a^{n}| =|a-b| (b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}a+...+ba^{n-2}+a^{n-1}) \geq n|a-b| \to \infty$. Hence the series $\sum (b^{n}-a^{n})$ does not converge.

Comment: What do you use here: $\left|b^{n}-a^{n}\right|=|a-b|\left(b^{n-1}+b^{n-2} a+\ldots+b a^{n-2}+a^{n-1}\right) \geq n|a-b|$ ? I have used some time to figure it out but can't.

Comment: @Xenusi In the sum there are $n$ terms and each term is at least $1$. So the sum is $\geq n$.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was: how do you obtain this identity $\left|b^{n}-a^{n}\right|=|a-b|\left(b^{n-1}+b^{n-2} a+\ldots+b a^{n-2}+a^{n-1}\right)$? Just to make it easier for myself. Let $b > a \geq 1$.

Comment: It is a basic algebra identity. Just like $(a-b)(a+b)=a^{2}-b^{2}$ @Xenusi

Comment: Sorry, had to look this up. So in summation notation $b^{n-1}+b^{n-2} a+\ldots+b a^{n-2}+a^{n-1}$ can be written as $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b^{k} a^{n-1-k}$?

Comment: Yes, that is right. @Xenusi

Comment: Alright. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $b >a\ge 1$;

MVT:

$\dfrac{b^n-a^n}{b-a}=ns^{n-1} \gt na^{n-1}\ge n$, where $s \in (a,b)$.